# GOOGLE SCRIPT EDITOR: TRYING TO APPLY SCRIPT TO ALL SHEETS EXCEPT FOR SPECIFIC ONES

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to exclude specific sheets from a script that is currently running on all sheets. The loop replaces empty cells with the text "placeholder names" across a single row designed to guide users to input data in designated cells only. However, I don't want the script to run on my main data source sheets - overwriting existing data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VV2b.png)

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const phData = [
    {c: "G4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 1"},
    {c: "H4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 2"},
    {c: "I4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 3"},
    {c: "J4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 4"},
    {c: "K4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 5"},
    {c: "L4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 6"},
    {c: "M4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 7"},
    {c: "N4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 8"},
    {c: "O4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 9"},
    {c: "P4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 10"},
    {c: "Q4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 11"},
    {c: "R4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 12"},
    {c: "S4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 13"},
    {c: "T4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 14"},
    {c: "U4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 15"},
    {c: "V4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 16"},
    {c: "W4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 17"},
    {c: "X4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 18"},
    {c: "Y4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 19"},
    {c: "Z4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 20"},
    {c: "AA4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 21"},
    {c: "AB4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 22"},
    {c: "AC4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 23"},
    {c: "AD4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 24"},
    {c: "AE4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 25"},
    {c: "AF4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 26"},
    {c: "AG4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 27"},
    {c: "AH4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 28"},
    {c: "AI4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 29"},
    {c: "AJ4", ph: "Placeholder TASK 30"},
    {c: "AK4", ph: "MERIT CRITERIA 1"},
    {c: "AL4", ph: "MERIT CRITERIA 2"},
    {c: "AM4", ph: "MERIT CRITERIA 3"},
    {c: "AN4", ph: "MERIT CRITERIA 4"},
    {c: "AO4", ph: "EXCELLENCE CRI 1"},
    {c: "AP4", ph: "EXCELLENCE CRI 2"},
    {c: "AQ4", ph: "EXCELLENCE CRI 3"},
    {c: "AR4", ph: "EXCELLENCE CRI 4"}
  ]
  phData.forEach((placeholders) => {
    const observedRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(placeholders.c)
    const clickedRange = e.range.getA1Notation()
    if (clickedRange === placeholders.c && observedRange.getValue() === placeholders.ph) {
      observedRange.setValue("")
    }
    if (clickedRange !== placeholders.c && observedRange.getValue() === "") {
      observedRange.setValue(placeholders.ph)
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const phData = [
```

#### To:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {

  // I added the below script.
  const excludedSheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,]; // Please set the sheet names you want to exclude.
  if (excludedSheetNames.includes(e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName())) return;

  const phData = [
```

- In this modification, when the active sheet is one of sheets of `const excludedSheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,]`, the script is not run.
- If you want to run the script, when the active sheet is one of sheets of `const excludedSheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,]`, please modify `if (excludedSheetNames.includes(e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName())) return;` to `if (!excludedSheetNames.includes(e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName())) return;`.

Comment: @natsun87 About `Thank you, your script worked perfectly.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer